# Export all data regardless of pagination in datatables

Tags: php, datatables

Here is what I'm trying to do.  I'm trying to export all of the data in a datatable regardless of the amount displayed on the page.

Based on the link: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/48044/export-all-regardless-of-pagination

I tried to do the following:

but guess what I'm only able to export the csv file with only a certain amount of records.

```
   var datatableFilters_{$this->id} = ".App_Json::encode($this->strictFilters).";
        var datatablePassthru_{$this->id} = ".App_Json::encode($this->passthruVariables).";
        $( document ).ready(function() {
            var datatable = $('#{$this->id}').DataTable(
                {
                    
                    ".(($this->allowExporting) ? "dom: 'Bfrtip', buttons: [ { extend:'copy',exportOptions: {modifier: {page: 'all', search: 'none' } }, }, { extend:'csv',exportOptions: {modifier: {page: 'all', search: 'none', serverSide: 'false' } }, }, { extend:'excel',exportOptions: {modifier: {page: 'all', search: 'none' } }, }, { extend:'pdf',exportOptions: {modifier: {page: 'all', search: 'none' } }, }, { extend:'print',exportOptions: {modifier: {page: 'all', search: 'none' } }, } ], " : '')."
                    ".(($this->showRecordsPerPageAtBottom) ? "sDom: 'Rfrtlip'," : '')."
                    serverSide: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    pageLength: {$this->recordsPerPage},
                    searching: ".(($this->allowSearch) ? 'true' : 'false').",
                    paging: ".(($this->allowPagination) ? 'true' : 'false').",
                    ordering: ".(($this->allowSorting) ? 'true' : 'false').",
                    info: ".(($this->showRecordCount) ? 'true' : 'false').",
                    language: {
                        search: '_INPUT_',
                        searchPlaceholder: 'Search...'
                    },
                    $order
                    ajax: {
                        url: 'ajax.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: function(d) {
                            d.ajaxAction = 'loadAjaxClassAction',
                            d.className = 'Browser_DataTable',
                            d.classFunction = 'ajaxProcess',
                            d.aryFunctionAttributes = jsonEncode([
                                '".get_called_class()."',
                                jsonEncode(datatableFilters_{$this->id}),
                                jsonEncode(datatablePassthru_{$this->id})
                            ])
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
```

Is there a way to export all records?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? The standard export process exports all records, regardless of pagination. (Filtering, on the other hand, does affect the number of rows exported by default - and using server-side processing instead of client-side can also limit the export).

Comment: After your edit, we can see that you are using `serverSide: true`. That (typically) means the server only sends one page of results to the browser - to avoid the need to send thousands/millions of rows to the browser, all at once. Therefore, DataTables only has access to that small subset of data which it was sent. You need to export data in a completely different way, in that scenario. We don't know exactly how you have implemented the server-side piece, here - so my notes are a best guess.

Comment: See the final Q in [this FAQ section about server-side](https://datatables.net/faqs/index#Server-side-processing).